# addClass with multiple results from find

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm using this function to add the class `hide` to the table row that contains the value of my variable `text`. The problem is that usually my `selected` `td` can get two values, but this function only works well with one value.

My tables:

```
<div id="csvtextcomptb" class="tableunform"><table cellspacing="1" 
cellpadding="1" border="1"><thead><tr><th>TABLE</th><th>TAG</th><th>DATE</th><th>STATUS</th><th>Key</th><th>Prev</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>COMP</td><td> COMP_TRUCK </td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>Prev(1)</td><td>CA5520</td><td>MP &lt; 1K</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>COMP</td><td> COMP_TRUCK </td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>Prev(2)</td><td>CA5520</td><td>MP &gt; 1K</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>COMP</td><td> COMP_TRUCK </td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>Prev(2)</td><td>CA5534</td><td>MP &gt; 1K</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>COMP</td><td>COMP_TRUCK </td><td>17/10/2017</td><td>Prev(2)</td><td>CA5328</td><td>MP &gt; 1K</td></tr></tbody></table></div>

<table id="filter_crca">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="pointer selected">MP &lt; 1K</td>
            <td class="pointer">MP &gt; 1K</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Function:

```
$(document).on("click","[id*='filter_'] tbody td", function(e){

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var prev = $(this).text().trim();
    var tbid = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    var regExp = /[^\*filter_]\w+/;
    var tableid = regExp.exec(tbid.toString());

    var tipotb = tableid.toString().split('_')[0]; 

    var text = $('#filter_' + tableid).find("td").map(function(){

        if( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {

            return $(this).text()

        }

}).get();

     $.each(text, function(index, value){

            $('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody').find("tr:contains('" + tableid.toString().toUpperCase() + "'):contains('" + value + "')").removeClass('hide');
            $('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody').find("tr:contains('" + tableid.toString().toUpperCase() + "'):not(:contains('" + value + "'))").addClass('hide');
            });
});
```

How can I change this function to read those values of `td` with `selected` class and merge them to add or remove `hide`?

Thanks!

Comment: provide more code , where is the id csvtex ? or  when it's created

Comment: @bRIMOs Done! Thank you

Comment: see my provided answer ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).on("click", "[id*='filter_'] tbody td", function (e) {
 var prev = $(this).text().trim();
 var tbid = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
 var regExp = /[^\*filter_]\w+/;
 var tableid = regExp.exec(tbid.toString());
 var tipotb = tableid.toString().split('_')[0];

 //Added code
 $('#filter_' + tableid).find("td").not(this).removeClass('selected');
 $(this).toggleClass('selected');
 var text = $('#filter_' + tableid).find("td.selected").text();
 $('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody tr').addClass("hide");
 //End

 $('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody').find("tr:contains('" + tableid.toString().toUpperCase() + "'):contains('" + text + "')").removeClass('hide');
 //$('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody').find("tr:contains('" + tableid.toString().toUpperCase() + "'):not(:contains('" + text + "'))").addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.selected {
 color: red;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="csvtextcomptb" class="tableunform">
 <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>TABLE</th>
    <th>TAG</th>
    <th>DATE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Prev</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>COMP</td>
    <td> COMP_TRUCK </td>
    <td>17/10/2017</td>
    <td>Prev(1)</td>
    <td>CA5520</td>
    <td>MP &lt; 1K</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hide">
    <td>COMP</td>
    <td> COMP_TRUCK </td>
    <td>17/10/2017</td>
    <td>Prev(2)</td>
    <td>CA5520</td>
    <td>MP &gt; 1K</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hide">
    <td>COMP</td>
    <td> COMP_TRUCK </td>
    <td>17/10/2017</td>
    <td>Prev(2)</td>
    <td>CA5534</td>
    <td>MP &gt; 1K</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="hide">
    <td>COMP</td>
    <td>COMP_TRUCK </td>
    <td>17/10/2017</td>
    <td>Prev(2)</td>
    <td>CA5328</td>
    <td>MP &gt; 1K</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

<table id="filter_comp">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="pointer selected">MP &lt; 1K</td>
   <td class="pointer">MP &gt; 1K</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont knkow if the below snippet is your need , but I've set some change in your code to sweet your demand , also you have wrong table associated to it's filter id !

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).on("click", "[id*='filter_'] tbody td", function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  var prev = $(this).text().trim();

  var tbid = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
  var regExp = /[^\*filter_]\w+/;
  var tableid = regExp.exec(tbid.toString());

  var tipotb = tableid.toString().split('_')[0];

  
  $('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody').find("tr").addClass('hide');
  
  $('#filter_' + tableid).find("td").each(function() {
    
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $('#csvtext' + tipotb + 'tb tbody').find("td:contains('" + text + "')").parent('tr').removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="csvtextcrcatb" class="tableunform">
  <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TABLE</th>
        <th>TAG</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Prev</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>COMP</td>
        <td> COMP_TRUCK </td>
        <td>17/10/2017</td>
        <td>Prev(1)</td>
        <td>CA5520</td>
        <td>MP &lt; 1K</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>COMP</td>
        <td> COMP_TRUCK </td>
        <td>17/10/2017</td>
        <td>Prev(2)</td>
        <td>CA5520</td>
        <td>MP &gt; 1K</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>COMP</td>
        <td> COMP_TRUCK </td>
        <td>17/10/2017</td>
        <td>Prev(2)</td>
        <td>CA5534</td>
        <td>MP &gt; 1K</td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>COMP</td>
        <td>COMP_TRUCK </td>
        <td>17/10/2017</td>
        <td>Prev(2)</td>
        <td>CA5328</td>
        <td>MP &gt; 1K</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<table id="filter_crca">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="pointer selected">MP &lt; 1K</td>
      <td class="pointer selected">MP &gt; 1K</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```